# x86 assembler pushf causes program to exit

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm

I think my real problem is I don't completely understand the stack frame mechanism so I am looking to understand why the following code causes the program execution to resume at the end of the application.

This code is called from a C function which is several call levels deep and the pushf causes program execution to revert back several levels through the stack and completely exit the program.

Since my work around works as expected I would like to know why using the pushf instruction appears to be (I assume) corrupting the stack.

In the routines I usually setup and clean up the stack with :
sub rsp, 28h
...
add rsp, 28h

However I noticed that this is only necessary when the assembly code calls a C function.

So I tried removing this from both routines but it made no difference.  SaveFlagsCmb is an assembly function but could easily be a macro.

The code represents an emulated 6809 CPU Rora (Rotate Right Register A).

```
PUBLIC Rora_I_A ; Op 46 - Rotate Right through Carry A reg
Rora_I_A PROC
    sub rsp, 28h
    ; Restore Flags
    mov cx, word ptr [x86flags]
    push cx
    popf
    ; Rotate Right the byte and save the FLAGS
    rcr byte ptr [q_s+AREG], 1
    ; rcr only affects Carry.  Save the Carry first in dx then
    ; add 0 to result to trigger Zero and Sign/Neg flags
    pushf ; this causes jump to end of program ????
    pop dx ; this line never reached
    and dx, CF ; Save only Carry Flag
    add [q_s+AREG], 0 ; trigger NZ flags
    mov rcx, NF+ZF+CF ; Flag Mask NZ
    Call SaveFlagsCmb ;  NZ from the add and CF saved in dx
    add rsp, 28h
    ret
Rora_I_A ENDP
```

However if I use this code it works as expected:

```
PUBLIC Rora_I_A ; Op 46 - Rotate Right through Carry A reg
Rora_I_A PROC
    ; sub rsp, 28h ; works with or without this!!!
    ; Restore Flags
    mov ah, byte ptr [x86flags+LSB]
    sahf
    ; Rotate Right the byte and save the FLAGS
    rcr byte ptr [q_s+AREG], 1
    ; rcr only affects Carry.  Save the Carry first in dx then
    ; add 0 to result to trigger Zero and Sign/Neg flags
    lahf
    mov dl, ah
    and dx, CF ; Save only Carry Flag
    add [q_s+AREG], 0 ; trigger NZ flags
    mov rcx, NF+ZF+CF ; Flag Mask NZ
    Call SaveFlagsCmb ;  NZ from the add and CF saved in dx
    ; add rsp, 28h ; works with or without this!!!
    ret
Rora_I_A ENDP
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar (but with a 6502!) and having the same issue. pushf jumps back to my C code.

Answer (score 3):

Your reported behaviour doesn't really make sense.  **Mostly this answer is just providing some background not a real answer**, and a suggestion not to use `pushf`/`popf` in the first place for performance reasons.

Make sure your debugging tools work properly and aren't being fooled by something into falsely showing a "jump" to somewhere.  (And jump *where* exactly?)

---

There's little reason to mess around with 16-bit operand size, but that's probably not your problem.

In Visual Studio / MASM, [apparently (according to OP's comment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549540/x86-assembler-pushf-causes-program-to-exit/57550251?noredirect=1#comment101593270_57550251) `pushf` assembles as `pushfw`, `66 9C` which pushes 2 bytes.  Presumably `popf` also assembles as `popfw`, only popping 2 bytes into FLAGS instead of the normal 8 bytes into RFLAGS.  Other assemblers are different.<sup>1</sup>

So your code should work.  Unless you're accidentally setting some other bit in FLAGS that breaks execution?  There are [bits in EFLAGS/RFLAGS other than condition codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register), including the single-step TF Trap Flag: debug exception after every instruction.

We know you're in 64-bit mode, not 32-bit compat mode, otherwise `rsp` wouldn't be a valid register.  And running 64-bit machine code in 32-bit mode wouldn't explain your observations either.

I'm not sure how that would explain `pushf` being a jump to anywhere.  `pushf` itself can't fault or jump, and if `popf` set TF then the instruction after `popf` would have caused a debug exception.

Are you sure you're assembling 64-bit machine code *and* running it in 64-bit mode?  The only thing that would be different if a CPU decoded your code in 32-bit mode should be the REX prefix on `sub rsp, 28h`, and the RIP-relative addressing mode on `[x86flags]` decoding as absolute (which would presumably fault).  So I don't think that could explain what you're seeing.

**Are you sure you're single-stepping by *instructions* (not source lines or C statements) with a debugger to test this?**

**Use a debugger to look at the machine code as you single-step**.  This seem really weird.

---

Anyway, **it seems like a very low-performance idea to use `pushf` / `popf` at all**, and also to be using 16-bit operand-size creating false dependencies.

e.g. you can set x86 CF with `movzx ecx, word ptr [x86flags]` / `bt ecx, CF`.

You can capture the output CF with `setc cl`

Also, if you're going to do multiple things to the byte from the guest memory, load it into an x86 register.  A memory-destination RCR and a memory-destination ADD are unnecessarily slow vs. load / rcr / ... / `test reg,reg` / store.

LAHF/SAHF may be useful, but you can also do without them too for many cases.  `popf` is quite slow  (https://agner.org/optimize/) and it forces a round trip through memory.  However, there is one condition-code outside the low 8 in x86 FLAGS: `OF` (signed overflow).  asm-source compatibility with 8080 is still hurting x86 in 2019 :(

You can restore OF from a 0/1 integer with `add al, 127`: if AL was originally `1`, it will overflow to `0x80`, otherwise it won't.  You can then restore the rest of the condition codes with SAHF.  You can extract OF with `seto al`.  Or you can just use pushf/popf.

---

> `; sub rsp, 28h ; works with or without this!!!`

Yes of course.  You have a leaf function that doesn't use any stack space.

You only need to reserve another 40 bytes (align the stack + 32 bytes of shadow space) if you were going to make another function call from this function.

---

##### Footnote 1: pushf/popf in other assemblers:

In NASM, `pushf/popf` default to the same width as other push/pop instructions: 8 bytes in 64-bit mode.  You get the normal encoding without an operand-size prefix.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pushf:pushfd:pushfq)

Like for integer registers, both 16 and 64-bit operand-size for pushf/popf are encodeable in 64-bit mode, but 32-bit operand size isn't.

In NASM, your code would be broken because `push cx` / `popf` would push 2 bytes and pop 8, popping 6 bytes of your return address into RFLAGS.

But apparently MASM isn't like that.  Probably a good idea to use explicit operand-size specifiers anyway, like `pushfw` and `popfw` if you use it at all, to make sure you get the `66 9C` encoding, not just `9C pushfq`.

Or better, use `pushfq` and `pop rcx` like a normal person: only write to 8 or 16-bit partial registers when you need to, and keep the stack qword-aligned.  (16-byte alignment before call, 8-byte alignment always.)

Comment: @ Peter Cordes : I'm definitively single stepping stepping through.  I didn't pay attention to the rsp change amount when I was pushing/poping.  I'll let you know.  Thanks for the bt instruction tip.  I should have known that!

Comment: I was unable to step through the assembly past the pushf instruction so I am unable to determine what it is doing to rsp.  I am running in 64 bit mode! When I attempt to step past the pushf instruction one of two things was happening.  1. It would immediately exit the program and debugger! 2. It would not advance past the instruction no matter how many times I attempted to step and the only side effect was the rax register was being increment by 1 on each occasion.

Comment: @Walter: What debugger are you using?  Also, what machine code are you seeing for `pushf`?  Try using disassembly mode in your debugger to single-step the machine code, maybe that will shed some light.

Comment: @ Peter: Visual Studio 2015. The disassembly will have to wait (a few hours) until I get back to the system. I did briefly look at the disassembly and it was showing me the memory location of the pushf and the mnemonic but I couldn't identify the opcode. Give me an hour to grab a screen shot!

Comment: @ Peter: Ok got it.  In the disassembly window you need to explicit enable viewing the code bytes!  The pushf is encoded as 66 9C which pushes 8 bytes!!!  I have that logic in several places which luckily hasn't failed, but know I will go back and change that. Big thanks!

Comment: @WallyZ: `66 9C` is `pushfw`, it pushes 2 bytes.  `66` is the operand-size prefix.  So IDK why your code isn't working.  (`pushfq` / `pop rcx` would be more efficient, though, if you use `pushf` at all.)

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing, the super strange thing is a pushf\popf pair at the start of the application is fine, it's just later that causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in Visual Studio. I'm using 2022, so it's an issue that's been around for a while.

I don't know exactly what is triggering it, however stepping over one specific `pushf` in my code had the same symptoms, albeit with the code actually working.

Putting a breakpoint on the line after the `pushf` did break, and allowed further debugging of my app. Adding a `push ax`, `pop ax` before the `pushf` also seemed to fix the issue. So it must be a Visual Studio issue.

At this point I think MASM and debugging in Visual Studio has pretty much been abandoned. Any suggestions for alternatives for developing dlls on Windows would be appreciated!